# Complicated summary function -- is it possible to solve with R data.table package?

Tags: r, data.table

I am re-writing some R scripts which analyse large volumes of data (~17 million rows), and I thought I would try to improve it's memory efficiency by using the `data.table` package (which I am only just learning!).

One part of the code has been puzzling me for a bit. I can't post my original solution because (1) it is crap(slow!), and (2) it's very nuanced with regards to the data, and will just complicate this question.

Instead, I have made this toy example (and it really is a toy example):

```
ds <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
Obs=c(1.5,2.5,0.0,1.25,1.45,1.5,2.5,0.0,1.25,1.45), 
Pos=c(1,3,5,6,2,3,5,2,3,4))
```

Which looks like this:

```
    ID  Obs Pos
 1:  1 1.50   1
 2:  1 2.50   3
 3:  1 0.00   5
 4:  1 1.25   6
 5:  2 1.45   2
 6:  2 1.50   3
 7:  2 2.50   5
 8:  3 0.00   2
 9:  3 1.25   3
10:  3 1.45   4
```

For ease of explanation, I'll pretend that we are observing trains (each train having its own **ID**), moving across a linear one-way track, with observations (some value, not of import to the question) about the train being made at set positions (**pos**, here from 1-6) along the track. It is not expected that a train will make it the entire length of the track (maybe it exploded before making it to pos 6), and sometimes an observation is missed by the observer... The positions are consecutive (thus if we missed observing the train at position 4, but we observed it at position 5, we know it must have passed through position 4).

From the above data.table, I need to generate a table like this:

```
   Pos Count
1:   1     3
2:   2     3
3:   3     3
4:   4     3
5:   5     2
6:   6     1
```

Where for each unique **Pos** in my data.table ds, I have a count of the number of trains that made it to that position on the track (or further), regardless of whether the observation was made at that position on the track.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions as to how to tackle this, it would be much appreciated. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with data.table to know if this could be done! Or it could be incredibly simple problem to solve and I'm just slow :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Great question!!  The example data is especially well constructed and well explained.

First I'll show this answer, then I'll explain it step by step.

```
> ids = 1:3   # or from the data: unique(ds$ID)
> pos = 1:6   # or from the data: unique(ds$Pos)
> setkey(ds,ID,Pos)

> ds[CJ(ids,pos), roll=-Inf, nomatch=0][, .N, by=Pos]
   Pos N
1:   1 3
2:   2 3
3:   3 3
4:   4 3
5:   5 2
6:   6 1
>
```

That should also be very efficient on your large data.

**Step by step**

First I tried a Cross Join (CJ); i.e., for each train for each position.

```
> ds[CJ(ids,pos)]
    ID Pos  Obs
 1:  1   1 1.50
 2:  1   2   NA
 3:  1   3 2.50
 4:  1   4   NA
 5:  1   5 0.00
 6:  1   6 1.25
 7:  2   1   NA
 8:  2   2 1.45
 9:  2   3 1.50
10:  2   4   NA
11:  2   5 2.50
12:  2   6   NA
13:  3   1   NA
14:  3   2 0.00
15:  3   3 1.25
16:  3   4 1.45
17:  3   5   NA
18:  3   6   NA
```

I see 6 rows per train. I see 3 trains. I've got 18 rows as I expected. I see `NA` where that train wasn't observed. Good. Check. The cross join seems to be working. Let's now build the query up.

You wrote if a train is observed at position n it must have passed previous positions. Immediately I'm thinking `roll`. Let's try it.

```
ds[CJ(ids,pos), roll=TRUE]
    ID Pos  Obs
 1:  1   1 1.50
 2:  1   2 1.50
 3:  1   3 2.50
 4:  1   4 2.50
 5:  1   5 0.00
 6:  1   6 1.25
 7:  2   1   NA
 8:  2   2 1.45
 9:  2   3 1.50
10:  2   4 1.50
11:  2   5 2.50
12:  2   6 2.50
13:  3   1   NA
14:  3   2 0.00
15:  3   3 1.25
16:  3   4 1.45
17:  3   5 1.45
18:  3   6 1.45
```

Hm. That rolled the observations forwards for each train. It left some `NA` at position 1 for trains 2 and 3, but you said if a train is observed at position 2 it must have passed position 1.  It also rolled the last observation for trains 2 and 3 forward to position 6, but you said trains might explode.  So, we want to roll backwards!  That's `roll=-Inf`. It's a complicated `-Inf` because you can also control *how far* to roll backwards, but we don't need that for this question; we just want to roll backwards indefinitely. Let's try `roll=-Inf` and see what happens.

```
> ds[CJ(ids,pos), roll=-Inf]
    ID Pos  Obs
 1:  1   1 1.50
 2:  1   2 2.50
 3:  1   3 2.50
 4:  1   4 0.00
 5:  1   5 0.00
 6:  1   6 1.25
 7:  2   1 1.45
 8:  2   2 1.45
 9:  2   3 1.50
10:  2   4 2.50
11:  2   5 2.50
12:  2   6   NA
13:  3   1 0.00
14:  3   2 0.00
15:  3   3 1.25
16:  3   4 1.45
17:  3   5   NA
18:  3   6   NA
```

That's better. Almost there. All we need to do now is count. But, those pesky `NA` are there after trains 2 and 3 exploded. Let's remove them.

```
> ds[CJ(ids,pos), roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]
    ID Pos  Obs
 1:  1   1 1.50
 2:  1   2 2.50
 3:  1   3 2.50
 4:  1   4 0.00
 5:  1   5 0.00
 6:  1   6 1.25
 7:  2   1 1.45
 8:  2   2 1.45
 9:  2   3 1.50
10:  2   4 2.50
11:  2   5 2.50
12:  3   1 0.00
13:  3   2 0.00
14:  3   3 1.25
15:  3   4 1.45
```

Btw, `data.table` likes as much as possible to be inside one single `DT[...]` as that's how it optimizes the query. Internally, it doesn't create the `NA` and then remove them; it never creates the `NA` in the first place. This concept is important for efficiency.

Finally, all we have to do is count. We can just tack this on the end as a compound query.

```
> ds[CJ(ids,pos), roll=-Inf, nomatch=0][, .N, by=Pos]
   Pos N
1:   1 3
2:   2 3
3:   3 3
4:   4 3
5:   5 2
6:   6 1
```

Comment: +1 really nice solution and even better explanation. Could you say something about how you would expect this to compare to say `ds[ , list( Pos = 1:Pos[.N] ) , by = ID ][ , .N , by = Pos ]` as data gets bigger?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Nice alternative. `Pos[.N]` would be a new length 1 vector, passed to the `:` function to create a new `1:Pos[.N]` vector. I'd expect all those small vectors to clog up memory and cause more garbage collects. As number of trains increased that would bite more (more groups) than as number of positions increased, maybe.  If you test it, I'm interested in the result!

Comment: I don't really understand the data.table syntax, but the CJ looks expensive (conceptually, if not actually?); is there a solution like mine, where data.table identifies the max Pos by ID, i.e., getting us quickly to `nAtMax`? Maybe that's what @SimonO'Hanlon is doing?

Comment: @MartinMorgan Yes, good point. Maybe: `ds[,max(Pos),by=ID][,rev(cumsum(rev(tabulate(V1))))]`. Also added longer comment on your answer.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that the question gained some interest, been staring at this problem for a while. Thank you for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: Just noticed possible typo `ds[CJ(id,pos), roll=-Inf, nomatch=0][, .N, by=Pos]` - `id` maybe should be `ids`?

Comment: @Meep That would be a typo yes but where is it? All I can see is `CJ(ids,pos)`.

Comment: @MattDowle Great example & great explanation! Helped me to better understand data.table workings. Would love to see this in a vignette. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`data.table` sounds like an excellent solution. From the way the data are ordered one could find the maximum of each train with

```
maxPos = ds$Pos[!duplicated(ds$ID, fromLast=TRUE)]
```

Then tabulate the trains that reach that position

```
nAtMax = tabulate(maxPos)
```

and calculate the cumulative sum of trains at each position, counting from the end

```
rev(cumsum(rev(nAtMax)))
## [1] 3 3 3 3 2 1
```

I think this will be quite fast for large data, though not entirely memory efficient.

Comment: +1  I had the impression from the question and title that a `data.table` demonstration was requested since Meep explained that his example data and task were very cut down. The `rev(cumsum(rev(tabulate())))` does the exact task as asked but what if trains start at different points, the value of the observation becomes of interest, trains no longer explode, or there are trucks as well (2 columns of IDs)? Those are simple changes (switches) to the data.table query whereas in base there may be some head scratching?

Comment: Thank you for the solution, which was still far better than what I had! :) Matt is right in suggesting that the data may be more complicated, which is why I accepted his answer. If you're curious, what I am working on is actually DNA sequencing trace data, nothing to do with trains at all :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try as below. I have purposefully split it into many step solution for better understanding. You can probably combine all of them into one step as well by just chaining `[]`.

The logic here is that first we find final position for each ID. Then we aggregate data to find count of IDs for each Final Position. Since all IDs for Final Position 6 should also be counted for Final position 5, we use `cumsum` to add all higher ID counts to their respective lower IDs.

```
ds2 <- ds[, list(FinalPos=max(Pos)), by=ID]

ds2 
##    ID FinalPos
## 1:  1        6
## 2:  2        5
## 3:  3        4

ds3 <- ds2[ , list(Count = length(ID)), by = FinalPos][order(FinalPos, decreasing=TRUE), list(FinalPos, Count = cumsum(Count))]

ds3
##    FinalPos Count
## 1:        4     3
## 2:        5     2
## 3:        6     1

setkey(ds3, FinalPos)

ds3[J(c(1:6)), roll = 'nearest']

##    FinalPos Count
## 1:        1     3
## 2:        2     3
## 3:        3     3
## 4:        4     3
## 5:        5     2
## 6:        6     1
```

Comment: +1, Very nice use of `roll="nearest"`. I don't think `ds3` is necessary? - `setkey(ds[, list(N=max(Pos)), keyby=ID], N)[J(1:6), roll="nearest"]`

Comment: Thinking a bit about this, `roll="nearest"` will give wrong result, for example, if "6" were not present in the data at all and you do the join from 1:6, isn't it (will give "2" instead of NA or 0)?

Answer (score 1):

Some timings for reference:

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 2e7
nid <- 1e6
npos <- 20
ds <- unique(data.table(ID=sample(nid, nr, TRUE), Pos=sample(npos, nr, TRUE)))
# ds <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
#     Obs=c(1.5,2.5,0.0,1.25,1.45,1.5,2.5,0.0,1.25,1.45),
#     Pos=c(1,3,5,6,2,3,5,2,3,4))
setkey(ds, ID, Pos)

ids = ds[, sort(unique(ID))]   # or from the data: unique(ds$ID)
pos = ds[, sort(unique(Pos))]   # or from the data: unique(ds$Pos)

mtd0 <- function() ds[CJ(ids, pos), roll=-Inf, nomatch=0][, .N, by=Pos]
mtd1 <- function() ds[,max(Pos),by=ID][,rev(cumsum(rev(tabulate(V1))))]
mtd2 <- function() ds[, .(Pos=1:Pos[.N]), ID][, .N, by=Pos]
bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), check=FALSE)

identical(mtd0()$N, mtd2()$N)
#[1] TRUE

identical(mtd1(), mtd2()$N)
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result            memory               time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>            <list>               <list>   <list>          
1 mtd0()        2.14s    2.14s     0.468    1.26GB     1.40     1     3      2.14s <df[,2] [20 x 2]> <df[,3] [41 x 3]>    <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd1()     281.54ms 284.89ms     3.51   209.24MB     1.76     2     1   569.78ms <int [20]>        <df[,3] [24 x 3]>    <bch:tm> <tibble [2 x 3]>
3 mtd2()        1.63s    1.63s     0.613  785.65MB     7.35     1    12      1.63s <df[,2] [20 x 2]> <df[,3] [9,111 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```